# AngularFire2 Firebase Observable never ends (list is empty)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, observable, angularfire2

I'm trying to query an empty firebase list. The problem is that the observable method subscribe never finish and I can't show to user that ddbb list is empty.

The function getUserAppointmentsByDate(...) is calling getUserAppointments(...), where *this.database.list('/appointment/users/' + user_uid)* is an **empty** firebase list for the input user (user_uid).

how should I manage an empty query to firebase?

thanks in advance!

```
getUserAppointmentsByDate(user_uid: string, start: string, end: string) {

  if (typeof (user_uid) == "undefined" || typeof (start) == "undefined" || typeof (end) == "undefined") {
    console.error("invalid argument for getPatientReport");
    return;
  }

  return this.getUserAppointments(user_uid)
  .map(
    (appointment) => {
      return appointment
        .filter((appointment) => {
          var appointmentStart = new Date(appointment.start);
          var startFilter = new Date(start);
          var endFilter = new Date(end);
          //Filter old, not cancelled and not deleted
          return (appointmentStart.getTime() < endFilter.getTime())
            && (appointmentStart.getTime() > startFilter.getTime())
            && (appointment.status != AppointmentStatus.CANCELLED);
        });
    })
}

getUserAppointments(user_uid: string): any {
   return this.database.list('/appointment/users/' + user_uid) //*THIS IS AN EMPTY LIST
    .mergeMap((appointments) => {
      return Observable.forkJoin(appointments.map(
        (appointment) => this.database.object('/appointment/list/' + appointment.$key)
      .take(1)))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `this.database.list('/appointment/users/' + user_uid)` return a empty array. `Observable.forkJoin(appointments.map(` complete without emit any value (that is the expected way of forkJoin works). In this case, you have two options, handling in the complete function.

```
.subscribe(
  res => console.log('I got values'),
  err => console.log('I got errors'),
  // do it whatever you want here
  () => console.log('I complete with any values')
)
```

or handle in an `if statement`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
...
return this.database.list('/appointment/users/' + user_uid)
    .mergeMap((appointments) => {
      if (appointments.length === 0) return of([]);
      return Observable.forkJoin(appointments.map(
        (appointment) => this.database.object('/appointment/list/' + appointment.$key)
      .take(1)))
  })
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you really saved my day!! I used the of([]) method